# condition formatting based on formula's result

Tags: excel

I have a cell (AP21) containing a formula, and I want that the AP22 become black if the AP21 return empty string.
I am using conditionnal formatting but I not able to do that, because when I am using a formula to check the value of AP21, it's always considered as not empty because it contains a formula and not a text.
What I need is to evaluate in my AP22 the result of the formula of the cell AP21 and not the formula itself.

Any clue about how to do that please ?

Here is what I have to help you to understand me more

[image]

I tried also what is suggested in comments still didn't work

[image]

Comment: `=AP21=""`????? An empty string is not the same as a blank cell. It has nothing to do with `AP21` contains a formula or not.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well cuz i am translating from french to english, I will put a screenshot. And yes my problem is related to the formula. Sometimes I feel here people are here just to criticiize instead of trying to understand the problem which is not helpfull from your side

Comment: I thought your explanation was fine. My comment was that you can't use `ISBLANK`. Just check if the cell is equal to a blank string.

Comment: I never said I WANT TO USE ISBLANK, I am just trying to explain my problem, you can ignore isblank, and try to help with how I can use it ... If I show you that I am using ESTVIDE which is in french excel version you won't get me, so I thought it's called ISBLANK in english

Comment: It is called `ISBLANK` in English Excel, but as I mentioned, just check if the cell is blank string with `=""`. *Don't* use `ESTVIDE`.

Comment: I will edit my answer with print screen you will understand me more ! Please don't insist on the contains of the formula itself, it works fine but I can'"t show all of it cuz it's for work

Comment: "instead of trying to understand the problem which is not helpfull from your side"... not meaning to come across like that. It's just that unfortunately there are *many* low-quality questions on this site. Your question should aim to be a [reprex]. Remember that we are just volunteers here... we also have actual work to do.

Comment: Don't use `ESTVIDE`, as I said. `=AP21=""` is all you need. This was literally my first comment :-)

Comment: Yes I know maybe english is not the native langage to everyone and translation may cause miss understandings that"s why I said we can try to help by considering the person. Anyway please try to see the print screen and as I said I don't care about the ESTVIDE, if I can use another formula to solve my problem that's all I want

Comment: This is what I'm saying. I'm giving you the formula. The formula is: `=AP21=""`. Please try it.

Comment: I will try that and let you know in 1 hour thanks a lot during this time can you please tell me why the ESTVIDE doesn't work ? ESTVIDE = it takes into consideration that the cell is completly empty without any format and nothing ?

Comment: As I've been saying, a blank string `""` is not the same as an empty cell. `ESTVIDE` will *not* work. From the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/fonctions-est-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665?ui=fr-fr&rs=fr-fr&ad=fr): "la fonction ESTVIDE renvoie la valeur logique VRAI si l’argument valeur est une référence à une cellule vide". Une cellule qui contient `""` n'est pas vide.

Comment: From your last screen shot, I would delete the other rules that don't work

Comment: Yes of course, I just added them for the print screen to avoid adding multiple picture for each case that I tried

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for your help and as mentionned the missunderstanding was a translation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BigBen said in comments, you want to compare to an empty string

```
=$AP21=""
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it's fine that way, and a thanks to BigGen as well

Comment: @JustGreat - de rien. Ca fait presque 10 ans que je n'ai pas parle francais.

Comment: Tu es canadien je suppose ? car là bas vous parlez fr et eng.